# Picking noodles from a pot

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

Suppose there are $n \in \mathbb{N}$ noodles in a pot.
You pick two noodle ends at random.
What is the probability that you pick two ends that belong to the same noodle?

I tried to approach this problem as follows:

- For $n=1$, the probability is of course $1$.
- For $n=2$, there are $4$ noodle ends in the pot.
  For the first pick, it doesn't matter, which end you choose, which gives us the first factor $1$.
  Now there are $3$ ends left in the pot and since we want to pick an end that belongs to the first noodle, the probability of picking a fitting noodle is $\frac13$.
  Therefore, the probabilty of picking two ends that belong to the same noodle is $1 \cdot \frac13 = \frac13$.
- For $n=3$, there are $6$ ends in the pot.
  Again, the first pick doesn't matter and for the second pick, we should pick one of the remaining $5$.
  Therefore, the probabilty of picking two ends that belong to the same noodle is $1 \cdot \frac15 = \frac15$.
- Overall the probability for $n$ noodles should therefore be $\frac{1}{2n-1}$.

Is my thinking correct?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes. The first choice doesn't matter. The second choice is $1$ out of $2n-1$.

Comment: You could also justify this by noting there are $\binom{2n}{2}$ different equally likely ways to select two noodle ends (*where order of selection doesn't matter*) and $n$ of these ways result in both coming from the same noodle, giving an answer of $\frac{n}{\binom{2n}{2}}$ which simplifies to the same as you found.